# Reservation Database Model

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am new to Databases and I would like to ask if my database model is correct. I am trying to create a reservation module wherein users can reserve basketball courts starting from 6:00 PM until 10:00 PM only. So I have a reservation table wherein I have a reservation ID, user ID, reservation date, and reservation time. My reservation time's values are '6', '7', '8', and '9' which points out the time reserved. However, I am quite unsure with this model because records will be quite repeating. If a user reserves a court and he picks February 5 - 6:00 PM and another user picks February 5 - 7:00 PM, there will be two records with the same date, only with a different time. Is my model correct? Any help would really be appreciated for a newbie like me.

[image]

Comment: You can make a separate table of userid and reservation date as one user can do many reservation on same day.so one table will have r-id and r-time.. Other will have user-id abd reservation date ! And in other table combination will be a primary key Ofcourse

Comment: So I will have 3 tables in total?

Comment: No only 2 just decompose them but keep a foreign key in 2nd table to access it from first table while writing a query.let uid rid and rtime be in single table and uid and rdate in other table

Comment: So to clear things up, I would have 2 tables. The first one will have a Reservation Date and a User ID column, and the second one will have a Reservation ID and Reservation Time. Is this correct? Sorry for the questions, I'm really new to databases.

Comment: Little.correction other table will also have userid in it..if you have learned about normalisation ine database course you will come to know why we did it

Comment: If 2 tables are 1:1, then _probably_ they should be a single table.  If 1:many, then 2 tables and the 'many' table has the id of the other table.  many:many requires a 3rd table.